# discord.py: custom reason without duty necessarily write them and error message if you don't specify the user

Tags: discord.py

I've been programming with discord.py for 3 days and I'm a beginner, let's say ...
While trying to complete with all possible errors the mute command I noticed that I have to write a reason to execute the command (which I would like to be optional) and that when I don't specify the user the message "specify the user".
How can I solve it?

Here is the complete code

```
#mute
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member=None,*,arg):
    role = get(member.guild.roles, id=int("691009285634654229"))
    if not member:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=discord.Colour.red()
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name="Per favore specifica l'utente!",
            icon_url="'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/730639329453670420/DuscePeppe_FRIULI.png'"
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        return
    if (ctx.author == member):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=discord.Colour.red()
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'Non puoi mutare te stesso!',
            icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/730639329453670420/DuscePeppe_FRIULI.png'
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        return
    if get(member.roles, name='Mutato'):
        embed = discord.Embed(
           color=discord.Colour.red()
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'{member.display_name} è attualmente mutato',
            icon_url=f'{member.avatar_url}'
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        return
    if get(member.roles, name='Moderatori'):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=discord.Colour.red()
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'Non puoi mutare un moderatore!',
            icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/730639329453670420/DuscePeppe_FRIULI.png'
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        return
    if get(member.roles, name='Presidente ad Interim del LMII'):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=discord.Colour.red()
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'Non puoi mutare un moderatore!',
            icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/730639329453670420/DuscePeppe_FRIULI.png'
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        return
    if get(member.roles, name='Co-Triumvirato'):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=discord.Colour.red()
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'Non puoi mutare un moderatore!',
            icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/730639329453670420/DuscePeppe_FRIULI.png'
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        return
    if get(member.roles, name='Triumvirato'):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=discord.Colour.red()
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'Non puoi mutare un moderatore!',
            icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/730639329453670420/DuscePeppe_FRIULI.png'
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        return
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color=discord.Colour.green()
    )
    embed.set_author(
        name=f'{member.display_name} è stato mutato',
        icon_url=f'{member.avatar_url}'
    )
    embed.set_footer(text=f'Motivo: {arg}')
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color=discord.Colour.gold()
    )
    embed.set_author(
         name=f'{ctx.author._user} ha mutato {member._user}',
         icon_url=f'{member.avatar_url}'
    )
    embed.set_footer(text=f'Motivo: {arg}')
    embed.add_field(
        name='Utente mutato:',
        value=f'{member._user}',
    inline=True
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name='Mutato da:',
        value=f'{ctx.author._user}',
        inline=True
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name='Durata:',
        value='∞',
        inline=True
    )
    channel = client.get_channel(729553772547932190)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
@mute.error
async def mute_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=discord.Colour.red()
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name="Non ti è permesso mutare",
            icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/730639329453670420/DuscePeppe_FRIULI.png'
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: You can give `arg` a default value: `async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member=None,*,arg=""):`

Comment: ok i solved thank you very much!
Do you also know why it does not calculate "if not member:"?

Comment: If `member` is `None`, `member.guild.roles` will fail before you get to `if member`

Comment: I removed the `None` and put ` member.guild.roles` under `if not membe`r but the result does not

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the error message, if someone doesn't specify an argument (user) or a wrong/incorrect argument, you can use the following code.

```py
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):

    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Error", description="You haven't specified the correct arguments.", color=0xff0000)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    elif isinstance(error, commands.UserNotFound):
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Error", description="I could not find the user.", color=0xff0000)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Error", description="There are some arguments missing!", color=0xff0000)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Error", description="An unknown error has occured, it has been logged on the bot console", color=0xff0000)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        raise error
```